# Scrapy returning unordered values when crawling

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I am new in Scrapy and I am trying to crawl this [page](https://www.amazon.com/best-sellers-movies-TV-DVD-Blu-ray/zgbs/movies-tv/ref=zg_bs_nav_0) and get the prices from the items, the problem is that scrapy is returning the values unordered and I don't know why.

This is my simple code

```
import scrapy
from ..items import AmazonItem
from scrapy.http import Request
import time

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "main"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://www.amazon.com/best-sellers-movies-TV-DVD-Blu-ray/zgbs/movies-tv/ref=zg_bs_nav_0',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):

        # amazon = AmazonItem()

        ol_response = response.xpath('//ol[@id="zg-ordered-list"]/li')

        for number_ra in range(0,50):
             response_div = ol_response[number_ra]
             price = response_div.css(".p13n-sc-price::text").extract()
             item_name = response_div.xpath("span/div/span/a/div/text()").get().strip()
             link = response_div.xpath("span/div/span/a").attrib['href'].split('/')[3].split('?')[0]
             print("({}) {} , PRICE: {}".format(number_ra+1,item_name,price))
             print(link+"\n")
```

The name and the id are in the correct order but not the prices.

Thanks, guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong way

You should iterate over each Item one by one

def parse(self, response):

```
for item in response.xpath('//ol[@id="zg-ordered-list"]/li'):
     price = item.css(".p13n-sc-price::text").get()
     item_name = item.css(".p13n-sc-truncate.p13n-sc-line-clamp-1::text").get()
     link = response.urljoin(item.css(".a-link-normal::attr(href)").get())
     print("{} , PRICE: {}".format(item_name,price))
```